# Solver for X - with a function

Tags: equation-solving

Sorry but I cant figure this out, Someone gave me some help on here yesterday but they didn't show their working so I could not redo what they did when my equation changed.

Can someone please help me solve for X and show me the way that you do this please.

```
S=360/(arccos(X/R)*2)
```

Thanks to anyone for any help they can give.

Comment: This site is for questions about Mathematica(TM), which is a software product. If you have questions about mathematics please post them in http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

eq = S == 360/(ArcCos[X/R]*2);Reduce[eq, X, Reals]

Out:R != 0 && S >= 180/[Pi] && X == R Cos[180/S]

or:Solve[eq, X, Reals]

{{X -> ConditionalExpression[R Cos[180/S], S >= 180/[Pi]]}}